# Entity Framework множественные связи между таблицами

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
public class Station : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }     
}


public class OperativeSchedule : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }                  //для таблицы station надо задать ключ          
    public virtual Station StationOfDestination { get; set; }             //для таблицы station надо задать ключ           
}
```

Нужно задать в таблице `Station` ключ для связи с `OperativeSchedule`. Сейчас при удалении Станции из `Stations` возникает исключение если `DispatchStation`  или `StationOfDestination` ссылаются на эту станцию.

Comment: Может быть это вам поможет http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Прочитал, но в описании нету примера с множественными связями.Если знаете как задать имена для DispatchStation и StationOfDestination в таблице Station, то напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: к сожалению сам еще не силен в Entity)

Comment: болше подходит http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx. Но там пример тоже 1 ко многим. а у меня 1 к 1.

Comment: Декларация связей через атрибуты обязательна? Fluent дает гораздо больше простора для действий...

Answer (score -1):

Вот тут есть краткое и хорошее описание и для один-ко-многим и для многие-к-многим: http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-03-code-first-conventions

Только у меня впечатление, что вопрос у вас не об этом, а о каскадном удалении и тогда вам нужно смотреть в сторону fluent API ([раз](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-05-fluent-api), [два](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-05-fluent-api-relationships)):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Category)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Давайте вы сформулируете вопрос поточнее. Я, например, не уверен, что вам нужна связь именно многие-ко-многим. Логика работы какая?